# Return values from a pass-through query via VBA

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, stored-procedures, vba, pass-through

I have VBA code to run a query in SQL-Server 2008. It runs fine and displays the table that I need. The code that does this is here:

```
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("MyStoredProcedure")

qdf.SQL = "exec [WCNS_Ops].[dbo].MyStoredProcedure [plus a bunch of parameters]"   
DoCmd.OpenQuery "MyStoredProcedure"
```

which displays this table:

[image: Picture of the table the stored procedure returns]

My question is this: How do I programmatically return these values to VBA code without displaying the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code is untested, but should get you pointed in the right direction:

```
Set db = CurrentDb

Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("MyStoredProcedure")
qdf.ReturnsRecords = True
qdf.SQL = "exec [WCNS_Ops].[dbo].MyStoredProcedure [plus a bunch of parameters]"  

With qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)  'could also be dbOpenDynaset, etc. '
    Do Until .EOF
        Debug.Print !firstid
        Debug.Print !lastid
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is execute the query and set its output to a recordset. Off the top of my head something like this

```
Dim dbCon as new ADODB.Connection
Dim rst as new ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd as new ADODB.Command

dbCon.ConnectionString=”Your Connection String”
with cmd
    .comandtype=adCmdStoredProc
    .commandtext=”Your SP name”
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Pram1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, “WhatEver”)
    .ActiveConnection=dbCon
    .NamedParameters = True
    Set rst = .Execute
end with

with rst
    if .EOF=false then
        myVar=!Column1
    end if
end with

rst.close
dbcon.close
set cmd=nothing
```